Connection to reverse interface dropped - UR5
i have installed 5.15.76-rt53, but it didn't work as expected. It still reported an error, but this time it was a little different:
[ INFO] [1720873969.508932034]: Robot connected to reverse interface. Ready to receive control commands.
[ INFO] [1720873975.622664768]: Received request to compute Cartesian path
[ INFO] [1720873975.624387838]: Attempting to follow 31139 waypoints for link 'tool_ros' using a step of 0.010000 m and jump threshold 0.000000 (in global reference frame)
[ INFO] [1720873976.552106491]: Computed Cartesian path with 31145 points (followed 100.000000% of requested trajectory)
[ERROR] [1720873977.292264538]: Sending data through socket failed.
[ INFO] [1720873977.292354495]: Connection to reverse interface dropped.
[ INFO] [1720873977.372595596]: Execution request received
[ERROR] [1720873977.400574305]: Can't accept new action goals. Controller is not running.
[ WARN] [1720873977.400910620]: Controller 'scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller' failed with error INVALID_GOAL:
[ WARN] [1720873977.401011718]: Controller handle scaled_pos_joint_traj_controller reports status FAILED
[ INFO] [1720873977.401071288]: Completed trajectory execution with status FAILED ...
[ INFO] [1720873977.402529277]: Execution completed: FAILED


a little different from what

what is your question? ... please add a focused, answerable question to your post
